# How to display the value of a html user input using JavaScript when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

How to display the value of a html user input using JavaScript when a button is clicked? I've tried, but it gives "[object HTMLInputElement]" instead of the user entered value.

Here's code.

```
<body>
<p>8 + 7 = ....</p>
<input type="text" name="ans" id="ans1" placeholder="Enter your answer here">
<button type="button" onclick="Game()">OK</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Clear()">Cancel</button>
<br><br>

<h1>A Simple Math Game</h1>
<p>
    <strong>Question 1</strong>
    <span id="question1"></span>
    <span id="answer1"></span>
    <span id="feedback"></span>
</p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("question1").innerHTML= "8 + 7 = ...";
    function Game() {
        let user = document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML= ans1;
    
    }
        
</script>
```

Here's the output I got.

8 + 7 = ....32  OK(button)  Cancel(button)

A Simple Math Game
Question 1 8 + 7 = ... [object HTMLInputElement] // this is the problem..!

Comment: `ans1` is a reference to the *element* which has *many* properties aside from it’s value. Why not `let user = document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML= ans1.value;`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```html
<body>
<p>8 + 7 = ....</p>
<input type="text" name="ans" id="ans1" placeholder="Enter your answer here">
<button type="button" onclick="Game()">OK</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Clear()">Cancel</button>
<br><br>

<h1>A Simple Math Game</h1>
<p>
    <strong>Question 1</strong>
    <span id="question1"></span>
    <span id="answer1"></span>
    <span id="feedback"></span>
</p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("question1").innerHTML= "8 + 7 = ...";
    function Game() {
        let user = document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML= ans1;
    
    }
        
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<p>8 + 7 = ....</p>
<input type="text" name="ans" id="ans1" placeholder="Enter your answer here">
<button type="button" onclick="Game()">OK</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Clear()">Cancel</button>
<br><br>

<h1>A Simple Math Game</h1>
<p>
    <strong>Question 1</strong>
    <span id="question1"></span>
    <span id="answer1"></span>
    <span id="feedback"></span>
</p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("question1").innerHTML= "8 + 7 = ...";
    function Game() {
        let user = document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML= ans1.value;
    
    }
        
</script>
```